# passing an array of structures from C# to C++ using IntPtr

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a structure -->

```
   public struct readers
   {
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1000)]
       public IntPtr[] tag_list;
   };
```

Marshalling has to be done in between "IntPtr[] tag_list" & structure TAG_IN_PARAM

```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   internal struct TAG_IN_PARAM
   {
       public int vis_cnt;
       public bool valid;
   }
```

Also its an array as => TAG_IN_PARAM[] tag_list = new TAG_IN_PARAM[1000];

I want to pass structure "readers" from C# to C++ DLL. However, i have been doing marshalling but garbage value is coming on DLL side.

// allocating memory
Marshal.StructureToPtr(tag_list[j], Reader.tag_list[j], false);

OR IF ANY OTHER WAY I CAN DO IT, PLEASE CONVEY.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a `public TAG_IN_PARAM[] tag_list`? I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: I want to pass structure "readers" from C# to C++ DLL. However, i have doing marshalling as -->                                                  for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
{                                                            readers.tag_list[j] = marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tag_list[j]));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(tag_list[j], readers.tag_list[j], false);
}

Comment: And what does the declaration look like on the other end?

Comment: Its --> class Readers
{
public: 
 TAG_IN_PARAM* tag_list; // array size must be tot_tags
};

Comment: Your `tag_list` field, is it a fixed size array?

Comment: Yes, its a fixed size array of 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ type that you are trying to match is, according to your comment:

```
class Readers 
{
public:
    TAG_IN_PARAM* tag_list;
};
```

That's a pointer to an array.

But your C# code declares an inline array. Your C# code would match this:

```
class Readers 
{
public:
    TAG_IN_PARAM tag_list[1000];
};
```

Obviously, that's not the way you want to go.

You'll need to change your C# code to make it match. Unfortunately it seems that the marshaller will not marshal an array as a pointer to the first element, when the array is inside a struct. Since the array is the only thing in the struct you should simply pass the array as a parameter.

Alternatively, if you absolutely need to pass the array in a struct then I think you need to marshal by hand. Like this.

```
public struct readers
{
    public IntPtr tag_list;
};
```

And then you can simply pin your array.

```
TAG_IN_PARAM[] tag_list = ...;
GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(tag_list, GCHandleType.Pinned);
readers r;
r.tag_list = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
// call function passing r
pinnedArray.Free();
```

Unfortunately that does not quite work because C# `bool` is not blittable. So you could resolve that by using a different type for that field. For example `byte` or `int` depending on what's on the C++ side.

Yet another option is `Marshal.StructureToPtr` on each field. That would run like this:

```
TAG_IN_PARAM[] tag_list = ...;
int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TAG_IN_PARAM));
r.tag_list = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(tag_list.Length*structSize);
IntPtr ptr = r.tag_list;
for (int i = 0; i < tag_list.Length; i++)
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(tag_list[i], ptr, false);
    ptr += structSize;
    // or on older versions of .net without arithmetic support on IntPtr
    // ptr = (IntPtr) (long)ptr + structSize;
}
// call function passing r
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(r.tag_list);
```

Comment: Thanks David. But i dont need to change TAG_IN_PARAM* tag_list to TAG_IN_PARAM tag_list[1000]. Now is it possible in other way? like anything on C# side to make it work for TAG_IN_PARAM* tag_list.

Comment: Read the answer again. I'm not telling you to change the C++ code. I'm not telling you to change to `TAG_IN_PARAM tag_list[1000]`. I'm telling you that your current C# code matches `TAG_IN_PARAM tag_list[1000]`. You need to change the C# code to match the C++ code.

Comment: Sorry i dint read it properly. But i tried different ways but still i dint get the proper values. Only first object is coming fine. In the next loop, its coming as garbage. It seems some size problem between two structures.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-remembered how the marshaller handles arrays inside structs. I updated the answer. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks David for the Info. I tried your code but it has thrown an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data." at GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(tag_list, GCHandleType.Pinned);

Comment: So, what does your `TAG_IN_PARAM` really look like? I assumed that it matched what was in the question. Because your `TAG_IN_PARAM` as per the question is blittable.

Comment: its the same David. i.e 
       internal struct TAG_IN_PARAM
       {
           public int vis_cnt; 
           public bool valid;
       }

Comment: Strange. `bool` makes the type not blittable. Not quite sure why. Use `int` instead would sort that out. Let me dig a little deeper.

Comment: OK, `bool` is just not blittable. Answer updated again. Sorry to have made such a meal of this. I've not done a great job.

Comment: You are providing a different ways though :) getting knowledge on marshalling. I have tried the second way here. and it again thrown an error during runtime --> Additional information: The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information at Marshal.StructureToPtr(tag_list, ptr, false). And david thanks for the effort. I really appreciate.

Comment: David, Your first solution worked by pinning an array. Thanks for the help. You are a genius :) however I just changed bool to byte. thanks again.

Comment: Gah, `StructureToPtr` requires blittable type. So, you'd need to do it element by element. Well, I updated the question that way. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: ohh nice. thanks again David.I was like struggling it since morning. This made by day ;)